# Why do we care if a power series has roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, automata, formal-power-series

I am reading up on Christol's theoreom and an important part is that k-uniform transducers (where k is somehow related to prime numbers) preserve the algebricity of a formal power series (taking the coefficients as a sequence). So basically, we start with a formal power series that has roots (my friend told me that algebraic means there are roots or zero crossings), run the coefficients through a k-uniform transducer and, when we use the values that come out as coefficients for a power series, that power series is again algebraic.

There is a lot I still need to understand here clearly (like, what is a "formal" power series vs a "business casual" power series...), but I'd like to start by understanding what is so special about a power series having roots.

Just for context, I have nearly no formal background in mathematics but came across Christol's theorem and thought it was very cool and maybe related to my area of work (computer science, temporal logics, and automata). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A power series usually is not algebraic. $\sin(x)$ , $\cos(x)$ an $e^x$ can be written as power seires, but they are transcendental.

Comment: The merit of power series is that we can approximate complicated functions in some interval with polynomials (which are much easier to handle) by truncating the power series somewhere. The structure of roots can be very complicated and is sometimes unknown (see the zeta function and the riemann hypothesis).

Comment: *Formal power series* roughly refers to treating power series as objects that can be added and multiplied (like power series do). In particular, you don't really intend to evaluate them, except at zero.

Comment: *Algebraic* means that it is a solution of a polynomial equation (if not otherwise specified with integer coefficients). So, a formal power series $f(x)=\sum_na_nx^n$ is algebraic if there is a polynomial $p(x)$, with integer coefficients, such that $p(f(x))$ is the series with all coefficients zero. Note that to compute $p(f(x))$ we only need to do multiplications and sums, which are the operations that can do with a formal power series $f$.